# $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, for all values of $x$, $x^2 - x \geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

I understand why this works, the proof does not make sense to me though:

[image]

How does he get the $-\dfrac14$, and why does it prove that the statement is true?

Comment: The author exploits the fact that $\left( x-\frac 12\right)^2≥0$ for all $x$. That is enough since any integer $≥-\frac 14$ must be at least $0$.

Comment: The author is [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

Answer (score 4):

If you want a more hands on approach, let's try cases. Note $x^2-x=x(x-1)$. Now if $x\geq 2$, both $x$ and $x-1$ are positive, so their product is as well. What happens if $x<0$? What about the remaining two cases?

Comment: Okay so, if x is negative, it'll  be a negative * negative, this satisfies the condition. if x is 1, the answer will be 0, this also satisfies the condition. The part that confuses me is how the author isolates the (-1/4) at the end of the proof. Does he move the (x-1/2)^2 to the other side of the equation?

Comment: @GurnoorAujla The author is using $(x-1/2)^2\geq 0$ to obtain $(x-1/2)^2+1/4\geq 1/4$.