# Prove that, for all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, if $A \cup B \subseteq A \cup C$, then $B \subseteq C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Apologize in advance for asking a question like this on this site, I have a final tomorrow, and there is no answer for this question so I have no other option but to ask. I need to know if this is True or False, and why.

Comment: `$A \cup B$` for example.

Comment: Please also accept the answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2929562/104041).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=B=\{1\}$ and $C=\emptyset$ (*i.e.*, the empty set).

The empty set is a great counterexample to a lot of would-be theorems, most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Not true in general.

For example, consider;

$$A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$
$$B=\{1,2,3\}$$ and $$C=\{1,2\}$$